# jquery send ajax post to zend controller action problems

Tags: jquery, ajax

ive got a form with jqgrid inside, and when the user click submit i want to submit data to a controller.
here is my form

```
<form method='POST' >
<div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 680;">
<span class="st-labeltext">Tags da ronda:</span>



<table id="toolbar2"></table>
<div id="ptoolbar2"></div>


<div class="clear" style="z-index: 670;"></div>
</div>
<div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 680;">
<span class="st-labeltext">Nome da ronda:</span>

<input type="text" name="nomeronda" id="nomeronda">




<div class="clear" style="z-index: 670;"></div>
</div>
<div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 680;">
<span class="st-labeltext">Tag Inicial:</span>


<select id="tagini" name="tagini">
</select>
<div class="clear" style="z-index: 670;"></div>
</div>
<div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 680;">
<span class="st-labeltext">Tag Final:</span>


<select id="tagfim" name="tagfim">
</select>
<div class="clear" style="z-index: 670;"></div>
</div>
<div class="st-form-line" style="z-index: 680;">
<span class="st-labeltext">Ordem:</span>


<select id="ordem" name="ordem">
<option value="Sim">Sim</option>
<option value="Não">Não</option>
</select>
<div class="clear" style="z-index: 670;"></div>
</div>
<div class="button-box" style="z-index: 460;">
<input id="button" class="st-button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="button">
<input id="button2" class="st-clear" type="reset" value="Cancel" name="button">
</div>
</form>
```

Now, when the user click submit button it activates this javascript code

```
<script language = "Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("‪#‎button‬").click(function(){
var param1 = 'first'; //or get value from some DOM element
var param2 = 'second'; //or get value from some DOM element

$.ajax({
url: '/rondas/choosetags/',
type: 'POST',
data: {param1: param1, param2:param2 },
dataType: "json"
});

});
});
</script>
```

So when the submit button is pressed, i make an ajax call to a controller name rondas, and the action name choosetags..
in this action im trying to see if the request is post and alert the data of the data that was sent to see if it is working.

```
if ($this->_request->isPost())
{
$this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

$param1 = $this->_request->getParam('param1');
$param2 = $this->_request->getParam('param2');
echo '<script>alert("'.$param1.'")</script>';
}
```

the problem is that my alert is blank..the alert is triggered but the $param1 value is null.
What is my problem...
i have tryed different solution found in here, but i cant see the alert of the $param1.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: In the Chrome/Firefox console, can you see whether or not the parameters are being sent along with the request? In Chrome, such info is found under the "Network" tab...

Comment: i am detecting the post, but the parameters that are sent are the input fields of the form, and not the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest if you serialize the form and send it as a string http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: according to the the page, serialize send me every values with the "name", i want the jqgrid rows inside, one way to resolve this is to create an input hidden field and the with javascript load the rows id on it, and then with serialize fetch all fields, but my problem still maintain, cant send parameters through $.ajax.

Comment: so the code is working know, i need to create a new action called saveronda, and change the url to /rondas/saveronda, becouse in my controller...